# When trying to delete a table from NDB Cluster, I get the error "4243: Index not found"

Tags: mysql, cluster, mysql-cluster

In a Linux-based NDB-cluster consisting of 7 API nodes, 1 Management node and 4 NDB nodes, I am trying to drop a table.

When I try to drop the table using MySQL Client, I receive the following error:

```
mysql> drop table table_name;
ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'database_name.table_name'
```

I should be able to drop tables in an NDB Cluster by using the MySQL Client, but after a short search on Google I found I could also use the ndb_drop_table tool.

I then got the following results:

```
./ndb_drop_table --ndb-nodeid=13 --ndb-mgmd-host=xx.xx.xx.xx:1186 table_name -d database_name
Dropping table table_name...
4243: Index not found

NDBT_ProgramExit: 1 - Failed
```

Searching for this error, I got exactly one (unanswered) result: http://lists.mysql.com/cluster/1608

As a last resort I tried to delete the entire database, but this command internally drops all tables first, so I got the same results:

```
mysql> drop database database_name;
ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'database_name.table_name'
```

Please advise on how to delete this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of searching, I found out the problem was caused by a MySQL version mismatch. We recently created tho new API nodes and installed the latest version of MySQL (5.6.11-ndb-7.3.2).

The results described in the original question occurred when trying to delete the table (stored on NDB nodes running MySQL 5.5.27-ndb-7.2.8) from one of these new servers.

The table could be deleted without trouble from an older host, also running MySQL 5.5.27-ndb-7.2.8. After downgrading the new API nodes to MySQL 5.5.31-ndb-7.2.13, these hosts no longer caused any trouble.

I hope this answer might help someone in the future.